Wrapping with React.StrictMode in Next.js
I have React.StrictMode set to true next.config.mjs of Next.js I am using for React project. Do I still wrap with <React.StrictMode> in the layout.tsx ?
Do both serve the same purpose?
I have page.tsx and layout.tsx in the Next.js project.

It depends on your purpose, in case you need to set strict mode to the entire application you can use the next.config.mjs file.
or you need to specifically set the component to strict mode you can wrap the the component alone with <React.StrictMode>.

No you don't need because it is enabled by default since Next.js 13-4

Since Next.js 13.5.1, Strict Mode is true by default with app router, so enabling it in next.config.js is only necessary for pages. You can still disable Strict Mode by setting reactStrictMode: false.
If you or your team are not ready to use Strict Mode in your entire application, that's OK! You can incrementally migrate on a page-by-page basis using <React.StrictMode>.
Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/reactStrictMode
